# Select remainder of data frame once the value of a column matches a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a data frame that has values of either 1 or 0. I'm attempting to get the portion of the data frame after the first 1 to 0 transition because I need to count the number of 0 to 1 transitions after that point

I tried `df.loc[df["column name"] == 0]` but the resulting dataframe only contains 0

I'm there's a simple method but I'm new to pandas.

Comment: Do you know that the column starts with a 1?  That is, do you have to look for the first 1 to 0 *transition* or can you just look for the first zero?

Comment: I actually just need to look for the first 0